# Constraining a Mixed-Integer Non-Linear optimization problem by L0-norm/number of non-zero elements in GEKKO

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, combinatorics, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I want to minimize the cost for achieving a given set of non-negative integer values b that are computed linearly from two sets of non-negative integer variables x, y in GEKKO.
If have stated my problem in a way, that the b's are constraints on the x & y. My cost function is non-linear: quadratic using a conditional/minimum. In addition to these standard constraints, I have a constraints which requires the number of non-zero elements in x is at least as large as the largest element in x (e.g. that the L0-norm is equal to the LInifity-norm).

My difficulty is now twofold, since I'm fairly new to optimization and a novice in GEKKO.

1. I saw that GEKKO supports numpy arrays which would make the problem statement rather concise, but I struggle to get it to work - resulting in a lot of list comprehensions instead of vectorized operations.
2. I managed to define the L0-norm constraint and GEKKO actually runs with it, but it fails to find a solution. I recognize that L0 problems are really hard (e.g. combinatoric), but somehow the solution is fairly easy to find by "hand". I feel just that I'm doing something wrong.

I would appreciate any help! Here is what I have done so far:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

# Setup gekko (taken from their MINLP tutorial with more iterations).
m = GEKKO()
m.options.SOLVER = 1  # APOPT is an MINLP solver
m.solver_options = ('minlp_maximum_iterations 500',
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10',
                    'minlp_as_nlp 0',
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 50',
                    'minlp_branch_method 1',
                    'minlp_integer_tol 0.05',
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.01')

# Define variables as arrays.
y = m.Array(m.Var, (7), value=1, lb=1, ub=12, integer=True)
x = m.Array(m.Var, (18), value=0, lb=0, ub=8, integer=True)

# Example of the user-defined target values b as constraints (actually input args).
m.Equation(x[2] + y[1] == 7)
m.Equation(x[12] + y[2] == 5)

# This is the L0 constraint.
# I thought using m.Array would make this a nice definition like 
#   m.Equation(np.count_nonzero(x) >= np.max(x))
# but it didn't, since these numpy functions are not supported in GEKKO.
# So I defined the following , which feels wrong:
m.Equation(m.sum([int(x_i.value > 0) for x_i in x]) >= max(x_i.value for x_i in x))

# Finally, the objective function (intermediates for readability).
k = np.array([m.min2(y_i, 3) for y_i in y])
x_cost = m.Intermediate(m.sum(x * (x + 1)))
y_cost = m.Intermediate(m.sum((k - 1) * (k + 2) + 2.5 * (y - k) * (y + k - 3)))
m.Obj(x_cost + y_cost)

# Solve.
m.solve(disp=True, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gekko uses gradient-based solvers so the equations shouldn't change iteration-to-iteration. There is a way to get the count of non-zero variables that is compatible with gradient based solvers. Here is an alternative form to give you count and max for your `x` vector. This uses `if3`, `max3`, and `min3` as found in the [documentation on Model Building Functions with logical conditions](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html?highlight=sos1#logical-functions).

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
# Setup gekko (taken from their MINLP tutorial with more iterations).
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Define variables as arrays.
y = m.Array(m.Var, (7), value=1, lb=1, ub=12, integer=True)
x = m.Array(m.Var, (18), value=0, lb=0, ub=8, integer=True)

# Example of the user-defined target values b as constraints (actually input args).
m.Equation(x[2] + y[1] == 7)
m.Equation(x[12] + y[2] == 5)

# This is the L0 constraint.
#   m.Equation(np.count_nonzero(x) >= np.max(x))
eps = 0.05 # decision point for a "zero" value
count = m.sum([m.if3(x_i-eps,0,1) for x_i in x])
max_x = 0
for x_i in x:
    max_x = m.Intermediate(m.max3(max_x,x_i))
m.Equation(count >= max_x)

# Finally, the objective function (intermediates for readability).
k = np.array([m.min3(y_i, 3) for y_i in y])
x_cost = m.Intermediate(m.sum(x * (x + 1)))
y_cost = m.Intermediate(m.sum((k - 1) * (k + 2) + 2.5 * (y - k) * (y + k - 3)))
m.Minimize(x_cost + y_cost)

# Solve.
m.options.SOLVER = 3  # Initialize with IPOPT
m.solve(disp=True)

m.options.SOLVER = 1  # APOPT is an MINLP solver
m.solver_options = ('minlp_maximum_iterations 500',
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10',
                    'minlp_as_nlp 0',
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 50',
                    'minlp_branch_method 1',
                    'minlp_integer_tol 0.05',
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.01')
m.solve(disp=True)
```

I used IPOPT to give a non-integer solution for initialization and then APOPT to find the optimal Integer solution. This approach produces a successful solution with x

```py
>>> x
array([[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0],
       [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0]],
      dtype=object)
```

and y

```py
>>> y
array([[1.0], [7.0], [5.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0]], dtype=object)
```

You probably aren't intending a zero solution for `x` so you may need to add constraints such as `m.Equation(count>=n)` or change `eps=0.05` to find a non-zero value or push the solver away from zero at a local minimum. With `m.Equation(count>=n)` and `eps=0.5` it finds a better solution:

```
n=3, obj=63
n=5, obj=52
```

Here is the solution of `x` and `y` when `obj=52` (best solution found).

```py
>>> x
array([[0.0], [1.0], [4.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0],
       [0.0], [1.0], [0.0], [2.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [1.0], [0.0]],
      dtype=object)

>>> y
array([[1.0], [3.0], [3.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0]], dtype=object)
```

You may need to adjust `eps` that is used in `if3` to adjust when a value is counted as non-zero or adjust `minlp_integer_tol 0.05` that is a solver option to determine the integer tolerance. Here is the final script with the additional inequality constraint that gives the best solution.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
# Setup gekko (taken from their MINLP tutorial with more iterations).
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Define variables as arrays.
y = m.Array(m.Var, (7), value=1, lb=1, ub=12, integer=True)
x = m.Array(m.Var, (18), value=0, lb=0, ub=8, integer=True)

# Example of the user-defined target values b as constraints (actually input args).
m.Equation(x[2] + y[1] == 7)
m.Equation(x[12] + y[2] == 5)

# This is the L0 constraint.
#   m.Equation(np.count_nonzero(x) >= np.max(x))
eps = 0.5 # threshold for a "zero" value
count = m.sum([m.if3(x_i-eps,0,1) for x_i in x])
max_x = 0
for x_i in x:
    max_x = m.Intermediate(m.max3(max_x,x_i))
m.Equation(count >= max_x)

# Finally, the objective function (intermediates for readability).
k = np.array([m.min3(y_i, 3) for y_i in y])
x_cost = m.Intermediate(m.sum(x * (x + 1)))
y_cost = m.Intermediate(m.sum((k - 1) * (k + 2) + 2.5 * (y - k) * (y + k - 3)))
m.Minimize(x_cost + y_cost)

m.Equation(count>=5)

# Solve.
m.options.SOLVER = 3  # Initialize with IPOPT
m.solve(disp=True)

m.options.SOLVER = 1  # APOPT is an MINLP solver
m.solver_options = ('minlp_maximum_iterations 500',
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10',
                    'minlp_as_nlp 0',
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 50',
                    'minlp_branch_method 1',
                    'minlp_integer_tol 0.05',
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.01')
m.solve(disp=True)
```

You may be able to adjust `n` or some solver options to get a better solution. I hope this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hey John! Thanks for all the effort! Indeed this really helped! W.r.t. your comment on changing equations between iterations - was this in regard to the equations being user-defined inputs? Because, these will be static for each optimization run, just between runs they might change. If not, where did the equations change between iterations?

The trick with the epsilon value is very nice (and probably something trivial for optimization people ;-) ).

Comment: The equation changing comment was in reference to this expression: `m.Equation(m.sum([int(x_i.value > 0) for x_i in x]) >= max(x_i.value for x_i in x))` where the count on the left side either includes `x_i` or not based on the value. The equations can't change each iteration of the solver where a variable is added or removed from an equation. An alternative way to do this is multiply each variable by a binary variable that switches between 0 and 1 with the if3 statement. Between runs, the equations can change because the inputs will be different.